# Room. Не работает запрос DISTINCT

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Не могу выполнить запрос. Нужно получить таблицу `Result` в итоге.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM User")
fun getAllUsers(): LiveData<List<User>>
```

---

```
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0,

    var dataId: Int = 0,
    var name: String = "",
    var userId: Long = 0
)
```

---

> The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id,dataId,userId] in com.example.xxxxx.domain.entity.User even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [name]

Comment: Ну так, интересно, а откуда взяться? `id`, `dataId`, `userId`, когда у вас стоит только `DISTINCT name`. Добавьте нужные колонки для генерации. И вам это в ошибки доскональна написали. Учите английский или пользуйтесь переводчиком

Comment: @FixiDens так,а если я добавляю, то тогда дубликаты остаются.

Comment: Используйте вложенный запрос или разбейте на части в чем проблема?

Comment: @FixiDens Можете примером помочь?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM User GROUP BY name"`